# How to get all data from Firebase Cloud Firestore for React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get/retrieve all the data from cloud firestore firebase for react native that I have created. But I am unable to do solve this issue. This is the image of my database that I created for firebase.

Firestore database

[image]

I tried to write this statement firebase.firestore().collection("cluster").doc("Joy"). But I am unsure how to display the data.

```
export default class TestSonglist extends Component {
constructor() {
super();

      var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("cluster").doc("Joy");

  docRef.get().then(function(doc) 
  {
      if (doc.exists) 
      {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
      } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
      }
  }).catch(function(error) 
  {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
}  
render() { 
return (
  <View>
    <Text>value={this.docRef}
    </Text>   
  </View>
);
  }
}
```

I should be able to retrieve the data from cloud firestore and show Joy and Love from document as a text/list.